# Count most repeated pair of an get that pair in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was working in a project for class and I don't know how can I get the direction (with the fields latitude and longitude) most repeated in the DataFrame. 
This is an example of the Dataframe I have:

```
                                  coor      lats      longs
0           {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
1            {-8.4228133, 43.34566085} -8.422813  43.345661
2           {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
3            {-8.4228133, 43.34566085} -8.422813  43.345661
4           {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
5           {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
6           {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
7           {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
8           {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
9           {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
10           {-8.4228133, 43.34566085} -8.422813  43.345661
11           {-8.4228133, 43.34566085} -8.422813  43.345661
12          {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
13          {-8.51114625, 42.90692115} -8.511146  42.906921
14           {-8.4228133, 43.34566085} -8.422813  43.345661
15           {-8.4228133, 43.34566085} -8.422813  43.345661
```

I execute this:

```
coords.groupby(['longs','lats']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)[:5]
```

Where coords is the name of the DataFile. And I get something like this:

```
longs      lats     
43.345661  -8.422813    303
42.906921  -8.511146    194
43.511210  -8.269336    120
42.798237  -8.866379     31
42.890181  -8.645030     19
dtype: int64
```

Here, if I try to access to the first element I get the number of times it appears (in this case I get 303) but I would need the latitude and longitude: longs: 43.345661 and lats: -8.422813.

Comment: just add `.reset_index()` to the end of your code and try again :)

Comment: @HarvIpan have you tested your code?

Comment: @RafaelC, my bad. Seems like your comment is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `reset_index` (*using only records shown in question above for dataframe*):

```
grouped_df = coords.groupby(['longs','lats']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame('value_count').reset_index()[:5]
print(grouped_df)
```

Result for grouped:

```
       longs      lats  value_count
0  42.906921 -8.511146           10
1  43.345661 -8.422813            6
```

Now to get first element you can use `.iloc`:

```
print(grouped_df.iloc[0])
```

Result:

```
longs          42.906921
lats           -8.511146
value_count    10.000000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```